# Pasting Excel data in PowerPoint chartData

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I need to create a PowerPoint slideshow with graphs. Data source for each graph is an Excel file.

I searched for a similar answer, but none seemed exactly my case.

The presentation is quite long and heavy.
A copy of the presentation (without macros) will be saved as a different file. It needs to be modifiable, so I copied data from Excel to dataChart for each chart in the slideshow.

First and main question: As I try to copy data, I get one of two errors. "Object doesn't support this property or method (Error 438)" or, in some other combinations, "Subscript Out of Range (Error 9)".

Second and minor question: any idea of a better structure for the whole operation?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape

Call openxcl 'see below

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.HasChart = msoTrue Then
            With shp
                'doing other things
                End With
            With shp.Chart
                .ChartData.Activate
                .ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1).Cells.Clear
                .ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:E6").Paste  'Here I get my error
                .ChartTitle.Text = shp.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value
                .ChartData.Workbook.Close
            End With
        End If
    Next shp
Next sld

End Sub

Sub openxcl()

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
xlApp.Workbooks.Open "C:\path\Source.xlsx", True, False
AppActivate ("Source.xlsx - Excel")

Dim test As Workbook
Set test = ActiveWorkbook
test.Sheets(1).Activate

With test.Sheets(2).Range("A1:E6")
    '.Select
    .Copy
End With

Set xlApp = Nothing
Set test = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Try the PasteSpecial method of the Range object instead `(ie ...Range("A1:E6").PasteSpecial)`.  However, while the line above it clears the data from all cells, it also cancels the copy mode.  As a result, you'll get the error `Run-time error 1004: PasteSpecial method of Range class failed`.

Comment: Solution is perfectly working. I used PasteSpecial and removed the previous line:
If you format it as an answer I can mark it as "answered"